# Checking linearity assumption of logistic regression using smoothed plot

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

I would like to check on the linearity assumption of my continuous variables in my logistic regression. I have produced some loess plots and I can see that they are not linear. What are the next step I should take? Is there any rough guide to the transformation that I should use on my variable by looking at the shape of my plot?

[image]
[image]
[image: Transformation suggested by @TenaliRaman]

The last plot is a transformation suggested by @TenaliRaman

Comment: Is "height", referring to height of people? Somehow I feel your graph for at least the height should be inverted. With very low probability you will see people with very small height. With very high probability, one would observe people with height of 5/6 and again with very low probability, one would observe people with very large height. One transformation that you can do, is to take the average height and for each instance, plot logit against the absolute distance to the average height. (For age, it is a bit unclear though).

Comment: @TenaliRaman Hello, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it still does not give near-linear relationship. The "height" is referring to height of plant.

Comment: Without some specified functional form in mind, I'd probably be looking at some form of spline model or loess to model it.

Comment: @Glen_b Hi, thank you for the suggestion. It would be great if you could recommend some reference on spline model

Comment: Depends on what you know, what you're trying to achieve and how much mathematics you have. Maybe first try 
Harrell, F. *Regression Modeling Strategies* for regression splines, or [this appendix chapter](http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Nonparametric-Regression.pdf) of  *Companion to Applied Regression* for smoothing splines and local polynomial regression (loess is essentially a version of that) or maybe Hastie and Tibshirani (1990) *Generalized Additive Models*. You may need something more introductory than those, but try one or more of those to start.